# How to set a DataSource on a JPA EntityMangerFactory that is not from JNDI

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm pretty new to JPA, having used JDO (DataNucleus) and Hibernate.

I get how to set up `persistence.xml` for the JPA configuration, but I need to make one tweak.  Instead of specifying the `DataSource` in the XML, I want to provide the actual `DataSource` object to the `EntityManagerFactory`.  I need to do this because I create and manage my own `DataSource` objects and do not rely on the container to do so, thus I cannot (and do not want to) look up the `DataSource` via a JNDI name in `persistence.xml`.

So, how to I provide a `DataSource` object to the `EntityManagerFactory` rather than specifying it in `persistence.xml`?  I can't imagine it's hard to do but I can't seem to find it, and I've looked all over the place.

If it helps at all, I'm using Hibernate 4 as the JPA provider (actually, I'm transitioning from 3.6 to 4, where the `Ejb3Configuration` class is gone).  Hopefully I can do it in a non-Hibernate specific way, but it's not a huge deal if I have to use Hibernate specific APIs.

Thank you!!!

-Ryan

Comment: do you use spring in your app?

Comment: Yes, you can do it in hibernate properties (which is inside entityManagerFactory bean) like this : <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/> where 'dataSource' is ref to your dataSource bean :) Just put this line below your persistence name definition.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using Spring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't figure out any way to do it myself so I used Spring to do it.  That's not necessarily bad, except that it required me to import a half dozen or so jars that I previously wasn't intending to use.  I ended up using them for other things anyway, but still, I think it's a real failure on the part of JPA that one can't even use the API to set a DataSource but must instead rely on a container-provided DataSource.

I used Spring's `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` to do the work.  It reads the configuration data from `persistence.xml` and I then set the `DataSource` via the Spring API.  Spring uses the `DataSource` to override what was defined in `persistence.xml`.

Here's what the code looks like.  Note the call to the `afterPropertiesSet` method.  This is required because my application does not use Spring for dependency injection or AOP, but instead uses Guice for those tasks.  If you don't call the `afterPropertiesSet` method then the call to `getNativeEntityManagerFactory` returns null.

```
  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
  factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
  factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("persistenceUnitName");
  factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
  factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

  EntityManagerFactory factory = factoryBean.getNativeEntityManagerFactory();
```

Answer (score 3):

If your are not using Spring you can do directly:

```
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    props.put("javax.persistence.nonJtaDataSource", createDataSource());
    props.put("javax.persistence.transactionType", "RESOURCE_LOCAL");
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnitName", props);
```

The property `javax.persistence.nonJtaDataSource` is documented as a JNDI URL but using Hibernate 5.1.4.Final works fine.