# How to use datasource from testcontainer in JEE entity manager

Tags: java, jboss, java-ee-6, entitymanager, testcontainers

In a project we are not using spring (wher exist gazillions of information about testcontainers) but a rather old jboss version 6.4.0.EAP with hibernate, which we cannot change. The testing framework is junit4 and to some extent arquillian.

I try to make integration testing better and want to use testcontainers at least for the database test setup. I know how to start a testcontainer (in that case mysqlcontainer) and how to run the existing liquibase scripts.

What I am stuck with is:
How to use the Datasource, which I can obtain here from my started container

```
public DataSource getDataSource(MySQLContainer<?> mySQLContainer) {
    MysqlDataSource ds = new MysqlDataSource();
    ds.setUser(mySQLContainer.getUsername());
    ds.setPassword(mySQLContainer.getPassword());
    ds.setURL(mySQLContainer.getJdbcUrl());
    return ds;
}
```

to create an entity manager which then should be injected into the existing Dao?
The Dao in the application is defined like

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyDao {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    protected EntityManager getEM() {
        return entityManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something like this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22137454/how-to-set-a-datasource-on-a-jpa-entitymangerfactory-that-is-not-from-jndi

I'm actually not sure if that's the right approach, but looks similar to your issue.

Comment: @VitalyChura I give this a try - it seems to be the way to go, there are just some problems inflicted by the overly complex setup of arquillian tests in the project. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

You do not use Spring for your JEE project, but you can use it for testing of datasource layer only.

What you need, is:

- to start mysql as docker container
- to apply DDL statements with liqubase to create tables, etc.
- [probably populate tables](https://github.com/AlexandrSokolov/datasource/tree/master/integration_tests#2-populating-test-data)
- and have access to `javax.persistence.EntityManager` in tests

Here is a simplified version, to get an idea:

```
@DataJpaTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate"})
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = { MySqlLiquibaseBaseIT.Initializer.class })
@Testcontainers
public class MySqlLiquibaseBaseIT {

  @Container
  public static MySQLContainer<?> mysql = new MySQLContainer<>(
    DockerImageName
      .parse(MySQLContainer.NAME)
      .withTag("5.7.22"));

  @Configuration
  @EnableJpaRepositories
  @EntityScan
  static class Initializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
      TestPropertyValues.of(
        "spring.datasource.url=" + mysql.getJdbcUrl(),
        "spring.datasource.username=" + mysql.getUsername(),
        "spring.datasource.password=" + mysql.getPassword(),
        "spring.datasource.driver-class-name=" + mysql.getDriverClassName())
        .applyTo(configurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment());
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase springLiquibase(DataSource dataSource) {
      SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
      liquibase.setDropFirst(true);
      liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
      liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yml");
      return liquibase;
    }
  }
}
```

Actually I do much more usefull things with the container, like:

- mysql custom configuration
- enabling container logging
- sql statements logging

[The full MySqlLiquibaseBaseIT class can be found here](https://github.com/AlexandrSokolov/datasource/blob/master/commons_test/src/test/java/com/savdev/datasource/MySqlLiquibaseBaseIT.java)

And in your tests you can just extend it and use either `DataSource` or `EntityManager` directly:

```
public class ExampleEntityIT extends MySqlLiquibaseBaseIT {

  public static final long ENTITY_ID = 25L;

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;
  @Autowired
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  @Test
  public void injectedComponentsAreNotNull(){
    Assertions.assertNotNull(dataSource);
    Assertions.assertNotNull(entityManager);
  }
}
```